# AG-Grid: Server side pagination in a redux app

Tags: react-redux, pagination, ag-grid-react

I'm using the **community version** of Ag-Grid in a react-redux application. Even though AG-Grid is generally compatible with redux, implementing **server-side pagination** seems to be impossible!

The reasons:

1. Redux is asynchronous - data update does not occur right after dispatching the action
2. The only way to update rows and counter (lastRow index) without re-rendering the whole grid, is via *successCallback* as part of the grid event

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution for this scenario on the web. I know that other developers raised very similar concerns a couple of years ago, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1751). However, no concrete update / info from the AG-Grid team is to be found.

Did anyone come across this scenario and was able to find a proper solution?

Do you know what is the official channel to reach the tech team and clarify that with them? ([AG-Grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/) does not suggest any concrete example).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read the [help], and ask on [meta] if you have any questions :)